# Slow performance for Kubernetes Ingress HTTPS load balancer on GCP

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, kubernetes-ingress

On GCP I setup a Wordpress workload on an auto-pilot cluster, then exposed the Wordpress through a TCP service, and finally setup an Ingress https load balancer. I used a Google managed certificate for the https connection.

However when I connect the https IP, the response is very slow, and all the JS and CSS cannot be loaded.

Then I tried create another Ingress controller but this time I used only http, switching back to plain http makes everything normal, and the site can be loaded successfully in a reasonable time.

May I know how can I fix the https connection's problem?